# What numbers have three Pythagorean partners in geometric progression?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Call two positive integers $\{m, n\}$ "Pythagorean partners" (PPs) if the sum of their squares is a square. Since all such pairs are of the form $\{2rpq, r(p^2-q^2)\}$ for some positive integers $p, q, r$ with $p, q$ of opposite parity, it follows that numbers with lots of factors also have lots of PPs. However, it seems to be very rare that a number has three PPs in geometric progression; restricting to the case where the GCD of the four numbes is 1, the first cases are 1365 with partners {196, 728, 2704} and 1456 with {735, 2730, 10140} (it's easy to see that they come in pairs with the same gap size, here 26/7) and the number of $d$-digit cases does not (at least not markedly) rise with $d$. Any ideas why? What can we say about such numbers?

Comment: But 196 and 1365 are not coprime

Comment: Gah, apologies - of course I meant to say that the GCD of the four numbers is 1. Fixed.

Comment: The question is completely incomprehensible. It is impossible not to use words that can be perceived ambiguously, but formally write down the question itself?

Comment: @individ as I understand it now, the question asks for describing the quadruples $(a,x,y,z)$ of positive integers such that $xz=y^2$; gcd$(a,x,y,z)=1$; and $a^2+t^2$ is a perfect square for each $t\in \{x,y,z\}$.

Comment: That sounds like counting rational points on the projective surface in P^6 = Proj k[a,x,y,z,u,v,w] cut out by xz=y^2 and u^2 = a^2 + x^2 and v^2 = a^2 + y^2 and w^2 = a^2 + z^2. If it were a smooth curve, you'd know whether there are finitely many rational points just from knowing the genus (and the rank, if g=1). I have no idea if arithmetic geometers expect anything similar (along the lines of the Mordell conjecture) for certain families of surfaces rather than for curves.

Comment: Perhaps, Aubrey, you could submit a list of the first few numbers to the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences? Also, any instances of numbers with more than three PPs? or is that impossible?